# Start terminal in directory QT

Tags: qt, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying to write a filemanager. Copy, remove functions work well. Now I need to add the Terminal function which will run terminal in the current directory.

```
void MainWindow::onCopyActionTriggered()
{
    // Get current index.
    QModelIndex cIndex = mainExplorer->currentIndex();
    if(!cIndex.isValid()) return;

    // Get path of file to be copied.
    QString cPath = mainExplorerModel->fileInfo(cIndex).absoluteFilePath();

    QMimeData *data = new QMimeData();

    QList<QUrl> urlsList;
    urlsList.append(QUrl::fromLocalFile(cPath));

    data->setUrls(urlsList);

    clipboard->setMimeData(data);
}
```

here is for example the Copy function

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on Ubuntu using Qt [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html), set `QProcess` program as `gnome-terminal`, the directory is set using `QProcess::setWorkingDirectory`.

You can write a function that takes the `directory` as an argument.

```
void MainWindow::startTerminal(QString directory)
{
    QProcess* p = new QProcess(this);
    p->setWorkingDirectory(directory);
    p->setProgram("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal");
    p->start();
    p->waitForStarted();
}
```